# Identify language and/or framework used to develop app

Tags: apk

I was wondering if it is possible to identify what language/framework was used to develop an android app given that I have access to the apps apk? For instance, can I tell if react native was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell if react native was used with some good accuracy by looking in the "lib" directory inside the APK if there is a library called `libreactnative.so`.

Comment: Its fun an interesting to see what other apps are using. This was a useful tip. Thanks :).